# Multiple User Sectioned Excel Workbook offline

Tags: vba, excel, simultaneous, multiple-users

The Company I am working for is looking for a workbook that can be accessed and edited simultaneously by different departments. They then want it sectioned so each department can only access their own information with one user having access to the whole lot.

A shared workbook may work, however, they want this to be local only, hosted on a LAN that the company uses. Does anyone know if this is possible with excel? If so, any ideas on how it could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a workbook for each department and set the network permissions so only members of that department can open the workbook. You might need to put the workbooks into separate folders to prevent other departments from being able to copy them. If you need to aggregate the workbooks into a "master view" then create a workbook with links from all the workbooks (a separate worksheet for each department).